Symmetry properties of the tangent modulus (strain energy function)
For a strain energy function W depending on the Lagrangian strain E,the Piola-Kirchhoff stress of the second kind can be obtained by

Sij = ∂W/∂Eij

and the tangent modulus by

Cijkl = ∂Sij/∂Ekl

The symmetry conditions apply

Cijkl = Cjilk , Cijkl = Cijlk , Cijkl = Cklij

If I check the second symmetry condition for the tangent modulus of the St.Venant-Kirchhoff material with

Cijkl = λ δijδkl + 2μ δikδjl

with i,j,k,l = 1,2,1,2 and i,j,l,k = 1,2,2,1 I obtain

Cijkl = C1212 = λ δ12δ12 + 2μ δ11δ22 = 2μ
Cijlk = C1221 = λ δ12δ21 + 2μ δ12δ21 = 0

I see this representation of the tangent module in various textbooks. However, I only get the same results if I symmetrize the expression in the second term with

0.5(δikδjl + δilδjk)

My question is:Why are the two calculated expressions not equal if I choose the non-symmetrized representation? I thought the symmetry of the strain tensor alone should make this verified symmetry condition valid.

The representation $C_{ijkl}=\lambda\delta_{ij}\delta{kl}+2\mu\delta{ik}\delta{jl}$ is probably a writing simplification meant only to act on the symmetrized strain tensor (i.e. $\epsilon_{kl}=\frac{1}{2}(u_{k,l}+u_{l,k})$).
This works out because the second term of $C$ can be written as the sum of a symmetric part (your $\frac{1}{2}(\delta_{ik}\delta_{jl}+\delta_{il}\delta_{jk})$) plus a skew part. However, the product of this skew part with the symmetrized strain tensor will always be zero, so it does not matter.
If you plan to act $C_{ijkl}$ directly on $u_{k,l}$ you need to use the version with the symmetrized second term.
This is just a guess though, I'd need to see the specific source to really know what's actually going on.
